# Detecting client timeout during uploads (serverside)

Tags: php, jquery, upload, timeout

On the first chunk of a large file being uploaded, we enter the file details into a database. if the user navigates away from the page. An ajax request is sent and the row is deleted. If their connection/power goes down however, no request can be sent and we end up with an orphan entry in our database.

Right now we check the timestamp of the last file part and anything which hasn't uploaded a chunk (1MB) in 10 minutes gets removed. We'd like to be able to speed up this process but if we cut down that time, users with slow internet connections may experience their files/records being deleted while waiting to upload.

We've thought of 2 solutions so far, the first is what we're using now, as explained above. The second would be to send a "keep alive" request from the user every X seconds, if the server goes Y seconds without receiving an update, the record is trashed.

The latter would seem to work faster but seems very inefficient. Has anyone done anything like this before? What is the best way of going about it?

Running Apache on Ubuntu, I am also using jQuery.

Comment: Yes, a garbage collection job seems like the right thing, I'd even make this my *only* way to do it (i.e. scratch the AJAX request). Just make the timeout longer, like >24 hours.

Comment: I should add that if the uploader was to come back to the upload page (where it lists their content, it's still visible and "uploading" - We have a button there for users to cancel it but it's not ideal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the user terminate the connection (no matter if by navigating away or closing the browser), the apache server will kill the PHP process (if there is no ignore_user_abort() in your PHP). In the [shutdown function](http://php.net/register_shutdown_function) you can check the [connection status](http://php.net/manual/bg/features.connection-handling.php) and if it is `aborted` or `timeout`, delete the file.

Comment: Wow, I've never even heard of this function before, looks promising though, thanks! | Edit: How would this work if each chunk was a seperate ajax call (it's a html5 uploader using javascript) Would this function trigger after every chunk in this case?